# How to fire CollectionChanged event in code for INotifyCollectionChanged/ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I define an ObservableCollection in ViewModel like:

```
//private ObservableCollection<MyObject> _myList;
public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyList {get;set;}
```

Then I try to bind it to SelectedItems for ListBox with behavior like:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
  <My:ListBoxSelectedItemsBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding MyList, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Then enable multiple selection for this listbox. It is fine when selceted more than one item by user interaction with mouse.

Question: initially, there are selected item data stored in database, when data is retrieved from database, I need to fire CollectionChanged and let those selectedItem display as selected in UI. Even I did RaisePropertyChanged in ViewModel for MyList when data is loaded, UI still not display those items as selected.  After debug the app, I found even MyList is loaded, CollectionChanged fired for Mylist in ViewModel, but CollectionChanged event not fired for the binding item SelectedItems in ListBoxSelectedItemsBehavior although it is bound to MyList.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Just so you're aware, is your code snippet intentionally ignoring the `_myList` member? Your property `MyList` technically doesnt use the private variable, at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
MyList.CollectionChanged+=new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(MyList_CollectionChanged);
```

from code behind hope it solves your problem.